# Delphi XE installation of Jedi JCL 2.6 on Win8 (x64)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, jvcl

So I have Delphi XE (no number) and I have a project that was built on another machine (using JVCL components). Now, my machine is a Windows 8.1 (64 bits), and the previous machine was Windows XP (32 bits).

Of course I want to be able to continue developing the app, but for that I need the JCL/JVCL to be installed here too.

Now comes my problem. When I run the installer (bat) of JCL, it starts ok, but it does not show any options, so when I click the Install button nothing happens, and I get a message saying the installation finished. But of course nothing is installed.

This is how the installer looks on my x64 machine:
[image]

What can I do to install this JCL on a win64 machine? I am very sure that this is the problem: the OS. Because on 32bit OS (Windows XP) I have no problem installing it.
I looked it up, but could not find a straightforward solution. There might be a problem with some registry where the installer looks for the location of Delphi ?!?! but I have no idea how to fix it.
I need to install the JVCL, but it wont install unless I have JCL installed first... and the JCL does not install

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't think x86/x64 would be an issue. Almost all modern computers are x64. I would expect the issue to be Windows 8.1. Have you tried running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I tried running as Administrator. No change. And I am 99% sure it's because of the x64 thing. The error does not appear only to me, but to other people in my situation. Look at this: http://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/thread_frameset.php?group=jedi.jcl Look at the 51-100 page, and you will se there another guy having this issue

Comment: You found someone describing the problem. [Two messages later](http://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/article.php?id=1233&group=jedi.jcl), he describes the solution. Did the solution work for you?

Comment: Actually, I do not understand his solution. He says he changed the registry keys in the pas files... But I do not find those registry keys. What could be what he is talking about looks like this:  `const
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  BCBKeyName          = '\SOFTWARE\Borland\C++Builder';
  BDSKeyName          = '\SOFTWARE\Borland\BDS';
  CDSKeyName          = '\SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS';
  EDSKeyName          = '\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS';
  DelphiKeyName       = '\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi';`  but what to change and into what?

Comment: I tried it again for the millionth time, downloaded a new clean JCL, and followed the instructions and so far it seems to work... at least installation of JCL is ok. But now, when i try to run the JVCL, doint as instructed on that page, the installer does not find any delphi installed, or dependencies... I will try to add the JVCL packages manually and I will let you know

Comment: I succeeded in the end to install the JCL. The JVCL is another story. I could not convince it to install automatically, so I did it manually. Package by package. I really think they should fix this version of installer. But that is just my opinion. Rob Kennedy, please post your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks